# Samsung smart tv emulator doesn't recognise .jpg image

Tags: javascript, html

I used this html tag as follows:

```
<img src="app\images\1.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
```

but the emulator doesn't show the image rather shows a question mark and debugger gives an error that requested url was not found on this server, whereas the file is very much there in the location.

Is there another way to insert image in samsung tv smart app?

Comment: "I used this html tag as follows:" ... Nothing there

Comment: The height and width attributes take integers or percentages, not CSS lengths. Get rid of the `px`.

Answer (score 1):

"directory" separators in URIs are forward slashes, not backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
<img src="app/images/1.jpg" height="100" width="100">
```

or

```
<img src="/app/images/1.jpg" height="100" width="100">
```

see the slashes / in stead of \ ?

On a server its allways /.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<img src="app/images/1.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
```